# How to draft posts after being published with x days

Tags: posts

I wanted to turn any of my published posts into drafts after X days. I tried doing it with multiple WordPress plugins, but they were no help. Can anyone help me do it?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use [`wp_schedule_event()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_schedule_event/) and create a custom hook that you trigger daily. This hook can then call a custom function in which you query posts with the desired publish date, and change their status.

For example, create a new plugin and add (note: I have not tested this):

```
// Schedule auto-drafting post event on plugin activation.
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'schedule_auto_draft_posts' );
add_action( 'auto_draft_posts', 'draft_posts' );
function schedule_auto_draft_posts() {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'auto_draft_posts' );
}

// Draft published posts based on the post's publish date.
function draft_posts() {

    $old_status = 'publish';
    $new_status = 'draft';

    // Example: get published posts made before last week.
    $posts = get_posts(
        array(
            'date_query' => array(
                array(
                    'column' => 'post_date_gmt',
                    'before' => '1 week ago',
                ),
            ),
            'fields' => 'all',
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'post_status' => $old_status,
        )
    );

    foreach ($posts as $post) {

        // Update the post status.
        wp_update_post(
            'ID' => $post->ID,
            'status' => $new_status,
        );

        // Fire actions related to the transitioning of the post's status.
        wp_transition_post_status( $new_status, $old_status, $post );
    }
}

// Clean the scheduler on plugin deactivation.
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'unschedule_auto_draft_posts' );
function unschedule_auto_draft_posts() {
    wp_clear_scheduled_hook( 'auto_draft_posts' );
}
```

Documentation:

- [Understanding WP-Cron Scheduling](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/understanding-wp-cron-scheduling/)
- If you would like to retrieve posts with your own date query, you could use [PHP's relative date formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php).

Documentation of the functions used:

- [`register_activation_hook()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_activation_hook/)
- [`add_action()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/)
- [`wp_schedule_event()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_schedule_event/)
- [`get_posts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/)
- [`wp_update_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_post/)
- [`wp_transition_post_status()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_transition_post_status/)
- [`register_deactivation_hook()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_deactivation_hook/)
- [`wp_clear_scheduled_hook()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_clear_scheduled_hook/)

Answer (score 0):

just two little comment to Cas Dekkers code.

1. At

```
        wp_update_post(
            'ID' => $post->ID,
            'post_status' => $new_status,
        );
```

it's should be an array:

```
        wp_update_post(array(
            'ID'       => $post->ID,
            'post_status'   => $new_status,
            );
        );
```

or

```
        $my_post = array(
            'ID'       => $post->ID,
            'post_status'   => $new_status,
        );        
        wp_update_post($my_post);
```

2. It can be set a custom time with using filters:

```
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'my_own_time_schedule' ); 
function my_own_time_schedule( $schedules ) {

  $schedules['one_minut'] = array(
    'interval' => 60, //seconds
    'display' => __( 'Once Minut' )
  );
  
  $schedules['ten_minutes'] = array(
    'interval' => 600,
    'display' => __( 'Every Ten Minutes' )
  );


  return $schedules;
}
```